# Prefix React className

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So, I need to prefix my react components classNames so it doesn't conflict with global classes.

And no, I can't use CSS modules because of how my yarn workspaces are built

So, if I have a `button` class I would like it to become `my_app-button`

```
<button className="button">Hello StackOverflow</button>
```

to

```
<button className="my-app_button">Hello StackOverflow</button>
```

PostCSS does that for me in the CSS part, but on the React Side I wasn't able to find a solution

---

All of my components use typescript

I've tried using a [webpack loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-classname-prefix-loader) to do the job, and it did! But only on my Storybook server, when I used it with my separate webpack config it didn't work

The only error that is given to me is [invariant 85](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=85)

This is my Webpack Config, alongside the [webpack loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-classname-prefix-loader) and the babel-loader

```
import { Configuration, ProgressPlugin } from 'webpack'

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env', 'minify'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-react',
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-typescript',
                'minify',
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'react-classname-prefix-loader?prefix=giffy_css', 
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader' }],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [new ProgressPlugin()],
}

export default config
```

and just in case you need it, this is my Storybook webpack configuration

```
webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,

      use: [
        {
          loader: 'react-classname-prefix-loader?prefix=giffy_css',
        },
      ],
    })
    // console.log(config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.overrides[0])
    return config
  }
```

i have also tried first compiling my components with babel and then using webpack
i tried searching for an equivalent [webpack loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-classname-prefix-loader) in babel, but could not find it

Comment: Can you provide more on why you want react elements to have a prefix?

Comment: The idea looks pretty complicated. It might be useful to take a look on Module CSS?

Comment: Have you found a way?